# Describing disparities in different levels

Tags: meaning, british-english

I am struggling to describe disparities in different levels.

Let's take an example, showing disparities in income between the different regions of UK.

[image]

1. Does the map show **country-level** disparities or **regional level** disparities?
2. And let's assume an increased variation of income in of the regions of UK. This means an upward trend in inequality in income. Should I call it **regional level** or **citizen level** trend?

Comment: I daresay regional would work. The map shows Scotland and Northern Ireland as (countries) having distinct disparity figures, but Wales (a country) is lumped in with the English 'North West' and 'West Midlands' ("Government Office Regions"), and for the rest of England, the 'North East' and 'Yorkshire and The Humber' GORs are combined, but the 'East Midlands', 'East of England', 'London', 'South East' and 'South West' GORs are shown separately.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey They might *all* be shown differently, but have the same value and therefore the same colour.

Comment: Yes, if adjacent countries or regions have the same value, the boundaries are omitted. If I were drawing up that map I might have included the Welsh/English border and those separating the English GORs which are shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_England)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I took a random map about UK from google to illustrate the post. If speaking about another country, not consisting of subcountries as UK, would you still use regional level? Thus, the answer for the second question will be citizen level if the first was regional level?

Comment: If you are comparing 'regions' then you can talk about a regional level. You could call Scotland, Wales, and Northern Ireland 'regions' of the UK, along with the Government Office Regions of England, namely North East, North West, Yorkshire and the Humber, West Midlands, , East Midlands, South West, South East, East of England, and Greater London. If you are comparing people in all of the regions with each other, I would call that a national level.